# neo4j return an integer instead of {high: 0, low: 10}

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to return just an integer through cypher?

I am working with neo4j and the javascript driver. However when I do a `count()` I get `{low: 10, high: 0}`. I would like to force this to return a low integer instead of the object above. Is this possible through cypher?

Note that I don't want to do this in the neo4j javascript driver and prefer to do this in cypher since I know it will be a low number...

Comment: Can you please share the whole Cypher query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cypher only works with Long and Double values. Javascript isn't able to adequately represent 64-bit Longs.

There's [advice here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type) from the Neo4j javascript driver for handling this when providing parameters to Neo4j queries, as well as for handling returned longs.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But is there a way to force neo4j to use Double values so that they appear in JS as ints? It's quite tedious to have to write bespoke JS logic every time I have a query that uses integers.

Answer (score 14):

> Starting from 1.6 version of the driver it is possible to configure it to only return native numbers instead of custom Integer objects. The configuration option affects all integers returned by the driver. **Enabling this option can result in a loss of precision and incorrect numeric values being returned** if the database contains integer numbers outside of the range `[Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]`.

```js
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  'neo4j://localhost',
  neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'neo4j'),
  { disableLosslessIntegers: true }
)
```

Keep in mind that `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `2^53-1 = 9,007,199,254,740,991`.

---

Sources:

- [Neo4j JS Driver on Github - Numbers and the Integer type](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#numbers-and-the-integer-type)
- [Neo4j JS Driver on Github - Enabling native numbers](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#enabling-native-numbers)

Answer (score 5):

Use `neo4j.integer.toNumber`. So basically when you want to represent such value, use something like

```
variable.toNumber()
```

You will get a good old `int` value.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See accepted answer. Neo4j works with 64-bit integers. Converting these to JavaScript representation without any check (for example neo4j.integer.inSafeRange) may lead to loss of precision. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver section Reading integers for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your simple handler for the transformation:

```
var transformIntegers = function(result) {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    try {
      result.records.forEach( function(row, i) {
        row._fields.forEach( function(val, j) {
          result.records[i]._fields[j] = neo4j.isInt(val) 
              ? (neo4j.integer.inSafeRange(val) ? val.toNumber() : val.toString()) 
              : val;
        })
      })
      resolve(result);
    } catch (error) {
        reject( error );
    }
  });
};
```

And as an example:

```
session
  .run('MATCH (A) RETURN ID(A) AS id, toInteger(10^20) as unsafe LIMIT 1')
  .then( transformIntegers )
  .then( function(result) {
    console.log(result.records[0]);
    session.close();
    driver.close();
  })
  .catch( function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of my object, I'm using this function found [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/180) to convert to JS-friendly number. Works great so far!

```js
function toNumber({ low, high }) {
  let res = high

  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    res *= 2
  }

  return low + res
}
```